# How to get a dropdownlist to post a form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a simple MVC view with a dropdown and a Submit button that posts the form and uses the value of the dropdown to change the view ("values" is populated in the controller):

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
<%=Html.DropDownList("values", "No value")%>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<%--rest of page here--%>
<% End Using%>
```

How can I set this up to change once the dropdown is changed, i.e. eliminate the Submit button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the onchange event to submit the current form:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("values", ViewData["ListData"],
                      new { onchange="this.form.submit();" })%>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use **jquery** to make the change

first add the class to your submit button and dropdown list as so:

```
     <%=Html.DropDownList("values", "No value",new {_class="dropdown"})%>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
```

then use jquery like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".dropdown").change({

   $(".submit").hide();
    })
  });
```